# Sitecore User Group Conference Europe 2023

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

[image: SUGCON logo]

**More info: https://europe.sugcon.events/**

Sessions will include community speakers and members of the Sitecore product and development teams. The goal of the conference is to share knowledge through the whole community, which includes beginner and advanced-level topics and presentations. The one-and-a-half-day agenda is full of education and sharing of great ideas from the community.

**Venue:** [Meliá Costa del Sol](https://europe.sugcon.events/Venue) (Málaga, Spain)

**When:** March 23th - March 24th, 2023

**Tickets:** https://sugcon-europe-2023.eventbrite.co.uk/ - **You can also sign up for an exam voucher, and you can use it for any exam on-site & the Content Hub Developer Certification Exam Preparation workshop+exam.**